# Not successful add migration in ASP.NET MVC and C#

Tags: c#, migration

I tried to add one more file in my model in ASP.NET MVC using C#. I already delete migration history, table, migration in Visual Studio, but it's not successful after I run `add-migration Customer`.

I get this is message:

> The Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot of your current Code First model. This snapshot is used to calculate the changes to your model when you scaffold the next migration. If you make additional changes to your model that you want to include in this migration, then you can re-scaffold it by running 'Add-Migration Customer' again.

Code after running `add-migration`:

```
namespace Web_Application.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    
    public partial class Customer : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.Customers", "CusGenID", c => c.String(nullable: false));
        }
        
        public override void Down()
        {
            DropColumn("dbo.Customers", "CusGenID");
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required]
public string CusGenID { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(100)]
public string Fullname { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Gender { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength (100)]
public string Contact { get; set; }

public int CustomerTypeId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("CustomerTypeId")]


public virtual CustomerType CustomerType { get; set; }

public bool Status { get; set; }
public string Note { get; set; }

public Customer()
{
    Status = false; // Status = false is New customer and it true is old customer
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when you make changes to your model classes after initially creating a migration, but before scaffolding a new migration.

The key things to try:

1>delete the existing migration files completely (the CS files in the Migrations folder).

2>make sure your model classes accurately reflect the current desired state of your database schema.

3>run Add-Migration again to generate a new "initial" migration snapshot.

4>mmake sure you deleted the old migration history table. This is usually named __MigrationHistory.

5>rebuild the project before re-running Add-Migration.

6>comment out any model annotations like [Required] temporarily - complex annotations can confuse the snapshot diff process.

7>mmake sure your DbContext is pointing to the correct database connection string.

as a last resort, delete the database and let Code First re-create it completely from the model classes.